# securing Ubuntu bootloader using TPM

Tags: hardening, tpm, boot

I am currently working with Ubuntu 16.04 , with an Intel CPU that supports TPM2 module.

I am trying to harden my boot-loader, i tried using trustedgrub2 fork that supports TPM2 , i understand that trustedgrub2 currently does not support UEFI BIOS so i switched to UEFI-CSM which should emulate the legacy BIOS , unfortunately after installing trustedgrub , the system still boots with the GRUB2.

I also tried using tboot , but it seems that there is almost no documentation to be found anywhere.

My questions are , is there any good tutorial for using/installing trustedgrub2?
or maybe is there any alternative to the options above to make the boot process more secure?

Thanks!

Comment: https://www1.cs.fau.de/filepool/projects/mark/index.html

Answer (score 1):

[Ubuntu supports Secure Boot](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot). This requires UEFI-only mode. Please disable CSM. The TPM can be used by the [Linux Integrity Measurement Architecture](http://linux-ima.sourceforge.net/).

- Back in the day, [apparently IMA was very immature](https://lwn.net/Articles/137306/).
- [Progress is made](https://lwn.net/Articles/699551/).
- It seems like IMA is compiled into Ubuntu since 14.04, according to [this page](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/IMA).

From what i've been reading, still some works needs to be done.

Comment: Your answer does not explain how to secure the _bootloader_.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps to run tboot:

```
Enable EFI booting mode in BIOS setup menu, enable VT-x, VT-d, TPM ,TXT in BIOS setup menu, save and exit
apt-get update
apt-get install tpm-tools
apt-get install mercurial
hg clone http://hg.code.sf.net/p/tboot/code tboot-code
cd tboot-code/tboot
make install
cd ../utils
make install
copy your /sbin/init to /boot
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
reboot
select tboot from grub boot menu
login as root
run txt-stat, after booting into ubuntu
```

Taken from here: https://sourceforge.net/p/tboot/wiki/Home/

Actually, on Ubuntu 18.04.1 it works like that:

```
sudo txt-stat | grep TRUE 
    senter_done: TRUE
    private_open: TRUE
    locality_1_open: TRUE
    locality_2_open: TRUE
    secrets: TRUE
    lock: TRUE
TXT measured launch: TRUE
secrets flag set: TRUE
TBOOT: TPM nv_locked: TRUE
TBOOT: TPM nv_locked: TRUE
```